# What's the difference between 売る and 売れる？

Tags: words

I looked up both words in a [dictionary](http://jisho.org/word/%E5%A3%B2%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B), but they both meant the same thing, "to sell".

I was confused because I've been playing around with verb conjugation, and one site told me that 売る was a godan verb meaning "to sell", hence naturally the potential form of this godan verb would be "売れる." However, it appears that "売れる" isn't merely a conjugated form of "売る” and is itself a verb, having its own conjugations....I'm confused

Maybe conjugations have conjugations?

Comment: It's rather an English problem where "sell" has [ambitransitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambitransitive_verb) usage.

Answer (score 6):

売る is a transitive verb which means "sell". 売れる is a specific verb because it has two types: a potential verb of 売る and an intransitive verb. It is generally used as an intransitive verb. The meaning of 売れる is written [here](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/21238/meaning/m0u/).

For example, the 売れる of この本は、よく売れる doesn't have the meaning as potential.

In addition, when [五段活用]{ごだんかつよう} verbs change to [下一段]{しもいちだん}活用 verbs, they sometimes become potential verbs and they are called [可能動詞]{かのうどうし}. For example, when a 五段活用 verb 書く changes to a 下一段活用 verb 書ける, it is a potential verb of 書く.